# Algorithm to check sequence numbers

Tags: objective-c

I need an algorithm to verify that the password is a sequence of numbers, tried a few, but I did not succeed. Is there any method ready for this?

EDITED: First I received this code in Java, and tried convert it to objective-c:

```
public static boolean hasSequence(String value) {
    boolean result = true;
    char[] chars = value.toCharArray()
            ;
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if(chars[i] - chars[i - 1] != 1) { // sequence is broken
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Any code at all? You'll need to show what you've tried etc...

Comment: At least some example of what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a straightforward conversion of the Jvaa code to Objective-C - drop conversion to `char[]`, and use `characterAtIndex:` method instead:

```
BOOL hasSequence(NSString value) {
    for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
        if([value characterAtIndex:i] - [value characterAtIndex:i - 1] != 1) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note that your Java code does not care if the characters are digits or not: any sequence of consecutive character code points, such as `"ABCDEFG"`, would be accepted.

Comment: Exactly, was using a NSMutableArray and the break was not working very well. Thanks.

Comment: if you're not going to use a while loop, it's a good habit to do something like `for (int i = 1, strln = value.length; i < strln; i++) {` to avoid recalculating length with each iteration. Probably doesn't add up to a millisecond here, but doing it each time you do a loop like this as a habit eventually matters...

Comment: @RobP That's right. I wanted to stay close to Java implementation, so I kept the loop as is. In this case, however, it's probably better to start at `value.length-1` and go back, to make sure that `length` is calculated only once. This applies to Java as well.